# How do I get the list of scope_identities for a inset into select using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a insert into select from a temp table. My problem is that I need to insert the items and also retrieve IDs of the inserted items in the insert statement.

How do I get the list of identity values that were inserted?

The code is below:

```
                 SELECT  O.OrderID,
                  O.SingleAgreementID ,
                  O.OrderTypeID ,
                  O.OrderStatusID ,
                  O.Reference ,
                  O.CreateDate ,
                  O.ValidityDate ,
                  O.DeliveredDate ,
                  O.PathologyID ,
                  O.DiscountTypeID ,
                  O.DiscountAmount ,
                  O.ValidityDays ,
                  O.DeductibleTypeID ,
                  O.DeductibleAmount ,
                  O.LimitOrder ,
                  O.Comments ,
                  O.CreatedUserID ,
                  O.StartPeriodDate ,
                  O.EndPeriodDate ,
                  O.GenerationDay ,
                  O.ParentOrderID ,
                  O.CanceledDate ,
                  O.CanceledUserID INTO #TEMPORDERS
                FROM    dbo.[Order] O
                WHERE   O.GenerationDay = DAY(GETDATE() -1)
                        AND  O.OrderTypeID = 2 
                        AND @Yesterday BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),O.StartPeriodDate,111) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),O.EndPeriodDate,111)



                INSERT INTO dbo.[Order]
                        ( SingleAgreementID ,
                          OrderTypeID ,
                          OrderStatusID ,
                          Reference ,
                          CreateDate ,
                          ValidityDate ,
                          DeliveredDate ,
                          PathologyID ,
                          DiscountTypeID ,
                          DiscountAmount ,
                          ValidityDays ,
                          DeductibleTypeID ,
                          DeductibleAmount ,
                          LimitOrder ,
                          Comments ,
                          CreatedUserID ,
                          StartPeriodDate ,
                          EndPeriodDate ,
                          GenerationDay ,
                          ParentOrderID ,
                          CanceledDate ,
                          CanceledUserID
                        )
                SELECT  TEMP.SingleAgreementID ,
                        TEMP.OrderTypeID ,
                        1 ,
                        TEMP.Reference ,
                        TEMP.CreateDate ,
                        GETDATE() + TEMP.ValidityDays,
                        NULL ,
                        TEMP.PathologyID ,
                        TEMP.DiscountTypeID ,
                        TEMP.DiscountAmount ,
                        TEMP.ValidityDays ,
                        TEMP.DeductibleTypeID ,
                        TEMP.DeductibleAmount ,
                        TEMP.LimitOrder ,
                        TEMP.Comments ,
                        'Orden Generada de manera automatica' ,
                        TEMP.StartPeriodDate ,
                        TEMP.EndPeriodDate ,
                        TEMP.GenerationDay ,
                        TEMP.OrderID ,
                        NULL ,
                        NULL 
                FROM #TEMPORDERS TEMP

--Get all Ids inserted HERE
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
--Get the IDs saved and insert the detail.
```

I don't know whether that is possible or not? Any ideas on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to fill a table with th new ID's

```
Declare @OutputTable table(aNewid int)

Insert into Table
........
Output inserted.ID

Select ....
from InputTable
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[Order] (
        SingleAgreementID
    ,   OrderTypeID
    ,   OrderStatusID
...
    )
OUTPUT INSERTED.[IdentityColumn] INTO #temp1
SELECT  t.SingleAgreementID
    ,   t.OrderTypeID
    ,   1
...
FROM #TEMPORDERS t

SELECT * FROM #temp1
```